# How can I link my SQL using a sessions to my ASP.Net(C#) web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a C# SQL query for my asp.net page which queries the database using a value stored in the session of my page (called tournyName).  I have the query working, and I am using a SqlDataReader (called myReader) to read the results of the query.  I cant however get the results to display on the HTML area of my page.
I have been piecing together bits of code that I have found from other peoples questions and the code at this point is incomplete. It looks something like this:

C# (snppit):

```
    conn.Open();
    query = "SELECT GamePlayer1 AS [Player 1], GamePlayer2 AS [Player 2], GamePlayer1Score AS [Score1], GamePlayer2Score AS [Score2] FROM Games WHERE (TournyName = '@TournyName')";

    com = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TournyName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200));
    com.Parameters["@TournyName"].Value = Server.HtmlDecode(tournyName.Trim());

    SqlDataReader myReader;
    myReader = com.ExecuteReader();
    myRepeater.DataSource = myReader;
    myRepeater.DataBind();
```

And my HTML, where I would like to display the results:

```
<asp:Repeater id="myRepeater" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate><table border="1"></HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<tr><td>
</td>
<td>
<%# Eval('Player 1')%>
</td>
<td>
 <%# Eval('Player 2')%>  
<td>
 <%# Eval('Score1')%>  
</td>
<td>
 <%# Eval('Score2')%>  
</td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

No matter what I try, the page just shows up as blank. Can anybody enlighten me as to how I would display this?

Comment: Have you debugged in and checekd what tourneyname actually is, and if the query you run returns any results.  Also, where is this code being placed in the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things:

- Since you are using a parameter (good!), you mustn't escape the parameter token in the SQL Query with quotes, i.e. just

> SELECT GamePlayer1 AS [Player 1], GamePlayer2 AS [Player 2], GamePlayer1Score AS [Score1], 
>       GamePlayer2Score AS [Score2] FROM Games WHERE (TournyName = @TournyName)

- Eval needs double quotes, i.e. `<%# Eval("Player 1")%>`

Also, remember to Dispose your connection, command and SQLReader.

Comment: Thanks for that! And yes I have disposed of my connection, I just didn't include that in my snippet of code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add an ObjectDataSource in your asp e.g.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="getPersonsDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="Players.Data" />
```

This is what actually runs your query and makes it available to the Eval method.

Comment: This is not a requirement, but may be useful.  Depends on how the code is structured.  In this case, I think that this is not what is needed.